# Unusual display resolution issue

Tags: user-interface, display, resolution

I have elementary OS on 2 ageing laptops and my main PC. Both laptops display properly but the PC is wonky.

Monitor is a 1920x1080 Samsung All-in-one Win 8.1.  I built an AMD64 based linux PC and am running elementary OS and Sparky on it, using the AIO as it's monitor through HDMI.

`xrandr` seems to indicate that it is displaying properly but UI elements are huge compared to the other 2 installations.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1
```

Wingpanel, window titlebars and many other elements are much larger than expected. 
[image: screenshot]

Cursor size sometimes grows much larger. There's always a small difference between browser windows(larger) and desktop (smaller) but in the file explorer windows (for example) it is much larger. Only while in the file list, not while on the left folder list. Sorry about crappy pics,had to use cam for this, screenshot not showing it.

[image: Small cursor] [image: Large cursor]

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, your problem is with the scaling factor of your UI. This might be due to the resolution the system is detecting.

To fix it:

- Install Tweak Tool (works in elementary).

  - `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
- Run Tweak Tool (`gnome-tweak-tool`).
- Find the Window scaling option under "Windows".
  [image]
- From here, you can adjust the scaling factor, until it looks as you would expect. **Be careful not to set it to too low of a value!**

Comment: Thanks - that adjusted the size of the title bar font down to a more expected level.  It did not change height of wingpanel or change the weird cursor size thing. Neither is a big issue just curiosities.

Comment: @DelDrew sorry about that, I had the wrong option (haven't used GTT in a while now). See my update, and again, my apologies.

Comment: No problem mate.  Thanks for the help.That brings up an issue I forgot. On many system

Comment: got cut off - many windows fail to draw properly. [link]http://i227.photobucket.com/albums/dd248/delawaredrew/Screenshot%20from%202015-07-05%20203227.png[/link]  I get loads of Gtk errors opening gnome-tweak-tools

Comment: @DelDrew Is this a stock install with the stock theme?

Comment: This way should be better instead of installing a tweak tool.  Get the actual scaling factor:  
`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor`

Set the scaling factor:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 0.9`

The factor 0.9 is an example.

Comment: @Stiffler as much as I like the command line, I like to offer a graphical option where possible as well. Many of our views will come from technical novices.

Comment: RolandiXor - yes all stock on this PC.

Comment: @RolandiXor - scaling at 0.6 right now, and in above photobucket link. notice the many missing elements of the GUI.  Few if any system windows render properly.  I do not know what settings I am missing in them.  Program windows draw normally except for the cursor size weirdness.